# How to inherit a class inside another class in wxPython?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, combobox, wxpython

I have researched heavily on how to get the variables from a different class in wxPython without much luck. My problem is that I want to update a combobox in the main window after the user closes the second window. I thought the best way to do this was to try to get the main window combobox variable somehow. Example:

```
import wx
class oranges(wx.Frame):

    #----------Main Window---------#

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Test',size=(1024,768))
        self.frame=wx.Panel(self)
        self.tickers=['Apples','a','1234']
        self.dropdown=wx.ComboBox(self.frame,choices=self.tickers,pos=(750,62),style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.get_stuff,self.dropdown)
        apples=wx.Button(self.frame,label='Click here',pos=(300,300),size=(100,100))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.plus,apples)
    def get_stuff(self,event):
        pass
    def plus(self,event):
        class orange(wx.Frame):

            #----------Second Window---------#

            def __init__(self,parent,id):
                wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Testing',size=(500,500))
                self.frames=wx.Panel(self)
                apples=wx.Button(self.frames,label='Collect Info',pos=(300,300),size=(100,100))
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.click,apples)
                self.what=wx.TextCtrl(self.frames,-1,'12',pos=(200,48))
            def click(self,event):
                asdf=self.what.GetValue()
                self.tickers=[]
                self.tickers.append(asdf)
                self.dropdown.Clear()
                self.dropdown.AppendItems(self.tickers)
                #Need to update dropdown#
                self.Destroy()
        if __name__ =='__main__':
            apps = wx.PySimpleApp()
            windows = orange(parent=None,id=-1)
            windows.Show()
            apps.MainLoop()
if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    window = oranges(parent=None,id=-1)
    window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I am really confused on how to go about fixing this problem.  Thanks in advance! I am looking forward to the answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
import wx
class SomeUserForm(wx.Dialog):
      def __init__(self):
          wx.Dialog.__init__(self,None,-1,"Enter User Info In this Frame")
          self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,pos=(50,50))
          self.txt2 = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,pos=(50,100))
          self.ok = wx.Button(self,wx.ID_OK,pos=(50,125))
      def GetValue(self):
          return self.txt.GetValue() + "::"+ self.txt2.GetValue()

class oranges(wx.Frame):
    #----------Main Window---------#
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Test',size=(1024,768))
        self.frame=wx.Panel(self)
        self.tickers=['Apples','a','1234']
        self.dropdown=wx.ComboBox(self.frame,choices=self.tickers,pos=(750,62),style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.get_stuff,self.dropdown)
        apples=wx.Button(self.frame,label='Click here',pos=(300,300),size=(100,100))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.plus,apples)
    def get_stuff(self,event):
        pass
    def plus(self,evt):
        dlg = SomeUserForm()
        if dlg.ShowModal() != wx.ID_OK:
            wx.MessageBox("User Cancelled Add!","Cancelled!")
            return
        self.dropdown.Append(dlg.GetValue())

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    window = oranges(parent=None,id=-1)
    window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

may do what you are asking for ...

Comment: That was an example of what was happening since the original code is < 1400 lines of code.  I am sorry as I probably wasn't clear enough, but I need the second class and window as I have many other inputs for the user.  Sorry I wasn't clear on what I wanted to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your parent Frame, add a method called `UpdateComboBox(self, newVal)` that takes in the new string... then since your popup is a child of that, just before you call `self.Destroy` in the child, call `self.GetParent().UpdateComboBox(asdf)` (where asdf is from your example, i.e. the string you want to pass back)